# Android - Endless scrolling with SuperSLiM

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, superslim

There is any way to implement endless scrolling to load more itens when i use SuperSLiM library?

Normally I'm used to use the LinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() method to help me to know when I need load more itens... but now, with linearlayout of SuperSLiM i can't use this.

How can i implement this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In place of LinearLayoutManager,use LayoutManager of superslim. I had implemented it in one of demo project. Row code for that is,

```
public abstract class EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
    private int previousTotal = 0; // The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
    private boolean loading = true; // True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
    private int visibleThreshold = 5; // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position before loading more.
    int firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;

    private int current_page = 1;

    private LayoutManager mlayoutManager;

    public EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(LayoutManager linearLayoutManager) {
        this.mlayoutManager = layoutManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
        totalItemCount = mlayoutManager.getItemCount();
        firstVisibleItem = mlayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        if (loading) {
            if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                loading = false;
                previousTotal = totalItemCount;
            }
        }
        if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)
                <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
            // End has been reached
            // Do something here
            current_page++;
            loading = true;
        }
    }
    public abstract void onLoadMore(int current_page);
}
```

I hope this will help you. :)

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.tonicartos.superslim.SectionData.<init>(SectionData.java:36)
 at com.tonicartos.superslim.LayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItem(LayoutManager.java:156)
 at com.tonicartos.superslim.LayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition(LayoutManager.java:187)
 at fourever.textile.notificationadapter.notifications$EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener.onScrolled(notifications.java:246)
 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchOnScrolled(RecyclerView.java:3704)

I got this error while using this.

Comment: how you call this class with recyclerview

Comment: @akhilbatlawala, you can use it with recyclerview.setOnScrollListener(..) like same as are using onClickListener.